# Text Not Displaying in Chrome Until After I Use Inspect Element

Tags: css, google-chrome

The problem is the whole website doesn't show text until I inspect element with Chrome. It all works fine on other browsers.

I don't have any chrome extensions installed and am using an incognito window, but still nothing.

The website passes validation via W3C - the site is: http://www.toricks.com

I'm using @font-face, which by looking at it seems to be setup fine!

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Comment: It seems like a bug in Chrome. I see what you describe in Chrome version 33, but in Canary (version 35) everything seems fine.

Comment: Hmm ok thanks for testing that for me!

Comment: Did you try setting a fall back font to your font-family? Like `font-family: Comfortaa, sans-serif;`

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) way of adding the `@font-face` like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Comfortaa';
    src: url('comfortaa.eot');
    src: url('comfortaa.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('comfortaa.woff') format('woff'),
         url('comfortaa.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('comfortaa.svg#comfortaanormal') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

I think this has the best cross-browser support. Make sure you convert your font to all the different types (you can do that with the Font Squirrel generator).